# wget adding headers to downloaded files when recursive

Tags: recursion, header, wget

I'm trying to download a dataset from an Apache server. I used the following command to download the files recursively using wget, downloading only files with the extension .vts:

```
wget -r -A vts <url>
```

However, it seems that wget is adding lines to the start of the downloaded files:

> ```
>  15:17:28 GMT
> ETag: "514256db-7df6c3567d200"
> Accept-Ranges: bytes
> Content-Length: 1098002907
> Vary: Accept-Encoding
> Connection: close
>
> <VTKFile ...
> ```

The first 6/7 lines are not in the original file, and when I use wget to download files individually, this is not added to the header. Is there a way to use wget recursively without having these headers added?

Answer (score 1):

Note that after headers there is blank line, so it looks like

> `--save-headers` Save the headers sent by the HTTP server to the file, preceding the actual contents, with an empty line as the separator.

was used, though clearly there is not such option in `wget -r -A vts <url>`. According to docs altering [Wgetrc](https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html#Sample-Wgetrc) file might

```
## Think well before you change them, since they may reduce wget's
## functionality, and make it behave contrary to the documentation:
```

though I do not know if it is possible to rig up to get behavior you described (i.e. saving headers but only when recursive download).
Anyway, in Wgetrc files above setting is written as `save_headers` so `save_headers = 0` should case headers to be not saved and `save_headers = 1` to be saved. Please examine Wgetrc file you are using with special attention to `save_headers`.

EDIT: comment *Exception has occurred: BadStatusLine x\n 15:17:28 GMT* suggest that for some reason server from what you are downloading elected to serve you response which does not comply with [RFC2616](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec6.html). First line of response should be

```
HTTP-Version SP Status-Code SP Reason-Phrase CRLF
```

where SP denote space character and CRLF denote carriagereturnlinefeed
so for example

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
```

This might explain why you got funky results. Note that `wget` was designed for being resiliant downloader, so you got some results in spite of using server which elected to go against `RFC2616`.

In such situation, only viable solution might be removing headers from files downloaded via `wget`.

Comment: I'm not sure where wgetrc is supposed to be located, I couldn't find it on my computer anywhere. So I simply copied the sample wgetrc you linked from the docs, and created one in "~/.wgetrc". There isn't a "save_headers" variable in the sample, so I created my own as you instructed, and set it to 0. Unfortunately, it still doesn't work. I even decided to write a python script which calls individual wget commands on each individual file to download, so that I don't have to use the recursive option, but somehow it still adds these headers. Is there perhaps an alternative to wget?

Comment: After I tried creating that .wgetrc, now my wget is consistently adding headers only, even when I'm downloading a single file with wget. I'm really confused now.

Comment: I installed wget on my Windows system, on both my laptop and desktop. Wget seems to be very inconsistent with adding the headers. When I try it the first time, it doesn't seem to add headers. However, after the first download, it consistently adds headers to my downloaded files. No matter what method I use to manually remove the headers, it corrupts the file somehow and I still cannot read it in.

Comment: @James if you already have `python` installed you might use [`urlretrieve`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html#urllib.request.urlretrieve) to retrieve single file rather than calling external tool

Comment: thanks for the reply. I just tried that, but I get "Exception has occurred: BadStatusLine x\n 15:17:28 GMT". The timestamp seems to be the first line of the header I get when I download the files.

Comment: @James this is some clue, I edited my answer

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I actually tried removing the headers manually, using sed and a regular text editor. Unfortunately, the files still end up being corrupt and cant be read with the tools they're supposed to work with (VTK and Paraview).